# Why didn't the squad going north bring any ravens with them?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The Night's Watch use ravens to send messages between castles, but also when going north of the wall, so the can alert the nearest castle as quickly as possible.

> In Season 7, Episode 6, a squad is formed to capture a wight. It is for sure a risky operation, so they would like to ask for help to Eastwatch-by-the-Sea as quickly as possible.

So why didn't they take any raven with them ?

Comment: Probably because you’d have needed a maester for the raven.

Comment: @Edlothiad well, they have [one](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Harmune) in eastwatch. And you don't have to be a maester to take a raven in a cage, or even take care of them in a daily basis, as Sam did it in castle black

Comment: Noise discipline would be my guess.

Comment: Maester, steward either way, they had no idea what they were going to find. Why bother wasting energy on the bird when it may be useless

Comment: @Edlothiad They had a fair idea of what they were going to find, they were out there seeking the worst weren't they? And as for the bird being potentially useless, Same can be said of your swords and armour. Why bother carrying all that weight when it may be useless in the case that you don't encounter any hostiles.

Comment: @Aegon in the universe, one is almost always carrying their sword, especially if they're knights. A raven? Those are normally left to Maesters/Stewards. I doubt they had a "fair idea" of what they were going to find. They were hoping to find a scouting party of some sort. They had no idea most of the wights would drop dead, one wight would scream and call for the army or that there would even be a scouting party. I'd say maybe they thought they'd find a lone wandering wight. And be able to bind him and run him back to Eastwatch quickly. No need for a squaking raven to ruin your stealth.

Comment: @Edlothiad I never said they knew _that would happen_. They however should have known that they might need ravens  Take The great Ranging for example. Mormont took ravens with him and a steward Samwell to tend to them. Jon is a Steward himself. What I am saying is, they ought to have gone in prepared. There's no point in building legs for the show-writers to stand on. It was a stupid episode where the whole plot was about Dany's rescue.

Comment: @Aegon I still don't see the need to bring ravens, in-and-out job, quick snatch-and-grab, there's no need for a raven to be sent out, what would you need it for if you didn't know you were going to be trapped by an army? I also disagree about the point of the episode. I think it was more about the loss of a dragon than actually having Dany be some sort of hero.

Comment: @Edlothiad The point is, They didn't know they wouldn't get trapped either. A raven is helpful in either case, regardless to whether they get trapped or not. It allows you to send word whatever shocking intel you might come across, it allows you to ask for help, it helps you send last words to your families whatever.  Think of it like this, imagine you are some Special Forces Team out there for a quick grab and run mission. Would you go out there without comms or would you rather go there with comms? Ravens might not be as advanced as our comms but they are still a mean

Comment: @Aegon But your comms aren't going to squak randomly and give you away. There are too many ifs and buts and maybes for taking a Raven with you and it working out better, Eitherway this is now becoming pointless lets keep this discussion within [our chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39179/the-quill-and-tankard)

Comment: I don't have a good "canon" answer, but nothing in that episode made any sense. I wouldn't worry about such details if I was you. Apparently it took 5 minutes here to run from high up in the North to the wall and 10 minutes to fly across the continent via dragon and a second or so for an entire army to go move on and go somewhere else. And don't tell me a lame screen time not equal movie time, that episode was beyond sloppy. So why take a raven with you? It takes longer to write a message than to deliver it in the world of that episode. It makes "sloppy" sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### In Universe

I can think of a couple of reasons why:

- Time: They were rushed, they needed to get a wight quickly to gain support of the Crown so they could prepare.
- Resources: They were clearly low on resources as they had few men and weapons. They didn't appear to have much even for the men that survived.
- Snatch and Grab: They were doing a snatch and grab mission a raven is not needed for such a scenario.
- Stealth: They were going for stealth, kill a scouting party and capture one wight. You do not need a raven for such a mission. Also a raven could be noisy and give them away.
- Didn't think they'd need it: In the above types of missions you wouldn't need a raven. They had no idea they'd face the full army so they didn't prepare for such an occasion.

Another reason that they could have known is that they had no idea a raven would even work. Bran sent a group of ravens North to scout out the army of the dead. When the Night King looked at them they scattered. It's unclear if this was because of the Night King, the ravens getting scared or Bran getting scared.

---

### Out of Universe

It was to add to the suspense of will Gendry make his run back in time before the others are killed? Will he make it at all? This is proven by him falling to the ground of exhaustion right as he made it to Eastwatch's gate.

Comment: The ravens clearly scattered Cuz bran saw himself looking at him and there minds were locked since the NK is bran